# How to add a cumulative column to an R dataframe using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850207/cumulative-sum-matching-ids), but I want to use `dplyr`:

With an R dataframe, eg:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 5)
                 , hour = rep(1:5, 3)
                 , value = sample(1:15))
```

how do I add a cumulative sum column that matches the id?

Without `dplyr` the accepted solution of the previous post is:

```
df$csum <- ave(df$value, df$id, FUN=cumsum)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Like this?

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 5),
                 hour = rep(1:5, 3),
                 value = sample(1:15))

mutate(group_by(df,id), csum=cumsum(value))
```

Or if you use the `dplyr`'s piping operator:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(csum = cumsum(value))
```

Result in both cases:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: id

   id hour value csum
1   1    1     4      4
2   1    2    14     18
3   1    3     8     26
4   1    4     2     28
5   1    5     3     31
6   2    1    10     10
7   2    2     7     17
8   2    3     5     22
9   2    4    12     34
10  2    5     9     43
11  3    1     6      6
12  3    2    15     21
13  3    3     1     22
14  3    4    13     35
15  3    5    11     46
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess to get the same output as the other approach, I'd need to finish with an `ungroup`?

Comment: @RacingTadpole No. If you want the `cumsum` over the whole table just don't put in the `group_by` in the first place.

Comment: I think the OP's question is if the `group_by` attribute sticks if you assign the result (`df <- df %>% group_by ...`), and the answer is that it does. If you don't follow with an `ungroup`, future operations on the reassigned `df` will act on the `id` column, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Just make sure that `plyr` is not active in your session. Took me some time to figure it out: `dplyr::mutate(cumsum=cumsum(value))`