# Cumulative summing between groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble structured as follows:

```
   day  theta
1   1    2.1
2   1    2.1
3   2    3.2
4   2    3.2
5   5    9.5
6   5    9.5
7   5    9.5
```

Note that the tibble contains multiple rows for each `day`, and for each `day` the same value for `theta` is repeated an arbitrary number of times. (The tibble contains other arbitrary columns necessitating this repeating structure.)

I'd like to use `dplyr` to cumulatively sum values for `theta` across days such that, in the example above, `2.1` is added only a single time to `3.2`, etc. The tibble would be mutated so as to append the new cumulative sum (`c.theta`) as follows:

```
   day  theta  c.theta
1   1    2.1     2.1
2   1    2.1     2.1
3   2    3.2     5.3
4   2    3.2     5.3
5   5    9.5     14.8
6   5    9.5     14.8
7   5    9.5     14.8 
...
```

My initial efforts to `group_by` `day` and then `cumsum` over `theta` resulted only in cumulative summing over the full set of data (e.g., `2.1 + 2.1 + 3.2 ...`) which is undesirable. In my Stack Overflow searches, I can find many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818427/how-to-add-a-cumulative-column-to-an-r-dataframe-using-dplyr) of cumulative summing within groups, but never between groups, as I describe above. Nudges in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this in `dplyr` I came up with a very similar solution to PoGibas - use `distinct` to just get one row per day, find the sum and merge back in:

```
df = read.table(text="day  theta
1   1    2.1
2   1    2.1
3   2    3.2
4   2    3.2
5   5    9.5
6   5    9.5
7   5    9.5", header = TRUE)

cumsums = df %>%
    distinct(day, theta) %>%
    mutate(ctheta = cumsum(theta))

df %>%
    left_join(cumsums %>% select(day, ctheta), by = 'day')
```

Comment: Excellent! The `distinct` function will come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

Not a `dplyr`, but just an alternative `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
# Original table is called d
setDT(d)
merge(d, unique(d)[, .(c.theta = cumsum(theta), day)])

   day theta c.theta
1:   1   2.1     2.1
2:   1   2.1     2.1
3:   2   3.2     5.3
4:   2   3.2     5.3
5:   5   9.5    14.8
6:   5   9.5    14.8
7:   5   9.5    14.8
```

PS: If you want to preserve other columns you have to use `unique(d[, .(day, theta)])`

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could use `split<-` and `tapply` to return the desired result.

```
# construct 0 vector to fill in
dat$temp <- 0
# fill in with cumulative sum for each day
split(dat$temp, dat$day) <- cumsum(tapply(dat$theta, dat$day, head, 1))
```

Here, `tapply` returns the first element of theta for each day which is is fed to `cumsum`. The elements of cumulative sum are fed to each day using `split<-`.

This returns

```
dat
  day theta temp
1   1   2.1  2.1
2   1   2.1  2.1
3   2   3.2  5.3
4   2   3.2  5.3
5   5   9.5 14.8
6   5   9.5 14.8
7   5   9.5 14.8
```