# Calculate total elapsed time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble(
  x = c(30, 60, 90, 30, 60, 90),
  phase = c(rep(c("phase 1", "phase 2"), each = 3))
)

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x phase  
#>   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1    30 phase 1
#> 2    60 phase 1
#> 3    90 phase 1
#> 4    30 phase 2
#> 5    60 phase 2
#> 6    90 phase 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Where `x` is the elapsed time (in seconds) within each `phase`. Since `phase` is something that happens continuously, I am interested in calculating the **total elapsed time**.

**Desired output:**

```r
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       x phase   elapsed_time
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1    30 phase 1           30
#> 2    60 phase 1           60
#> 3    90 phase 1           90
#> 4    30 phase 2          120
#> 5    60 phase 2          150
#> 6    90 phase 2          180
```

Any ideas? Please, note that my real example has much more *phases*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`. First we need to group by the `phase` and get the time differences for each. We then `ungroup()` and take the `cumsum()` as a total, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(phase) %>% 
 mutate(diffs = x - lag(x, default = 0)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(res = cumsum(diffs)) %>% 
 select(-diffs)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      x phase     res
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1    30 phase 1    30
#2    60 phase 1    60
#3    90 phase 1    90
#4    30 phase 2   120
#5    60 phase 2   150
#6    90 phase 2   180
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following post has the answer you're looking for:

[How to add a cumulative column to an R dataframe using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818427/how-to-add-a-cumulative-column-to-an-r-dataframe-using-dplyr)

It shows how to create a cumulative column using `group_by` and `mutate`. It appears you want the elapsed time to sum across both phases, so simply do not include the `group_by` call in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` solution. It finds the start of each phase, and adds this to x

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  x = c(30, 60, 90, 30, 60, 90),
  phase = c(rep(c("phase 1", "phase 2"), each = 3))
)

df %>% group_by(phase) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(start = map_dbl(data, max)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(start = lag(start, default = 0)) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(elapsed_time = start + x) %>% 
  select(-start)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   phase       x elapsed_time
#>   <chr>   <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 phase 1    30           30
#> 2 phase 1    60           60
#> 3 phase 1    90           90
#> 4 phase 2    30          120
#> 5 phase 2    60          150
#> 6 phase 2    90          180
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>