# Use a single, common group-specific baseline for calculations (cumsum) within sub-groups

Tags: r, optimization, tidyverse, cumsum

I'm looking for a tidy solution preferably using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)

This question is in line with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265719/1305688), it does however have an added twist. My data has an overall grouping variable 'grp'. Within each such *group*, I want to perform calculations based on cumulative sum (`cumsum`) within *sub-groups* defined by 'trial', here `X` and `Y`.

However, for the calculations within both sub-groups, trial "X" and trial "Y", I need to use a single, common group-specific baseline, i.e. where trial is `B`.

My desired outcome is `Value3` in the data set `desired_outcome` below:

```
# library(tidyverse)
# library(dplyr)
desired_outcome # see below I got this `desired_outcome`
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   grp [2]
   grp   trial    yr value1 value2 Value3
   <chr> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     B      2021      2      0      2
 2 A     X      2022      3      1      5
 3 A     X      2023      4      2     10
 4 A     Y      2022      5      3      7
 5 A     Y      2023      6      4     16
 6 B     B      2021      0      2      0
 7 B     X      2022      1      3      3
 8 B     X      2023      2      4      8
 9 B     Y      2022      3      5      5
10 B     Y      2023      4      6     14
```

My minimal working example. Data first,

```
tabl <- tribble(~grp, ~trial, ~yr, ~value1, ~value2,
                'A', "B", 2021, 2, 0,
                'A', "X", 2022, 3, 1,
                'A', "X", 2023, 4, 2,
                'A', "Y", 2022, 5, 3,
                'A', "Y", 2023, 6, 4,
                'B', "B", 2021, 0, 2,
                'B', "X", 2022, 1, 3,
                'B', "X", 2023, 2, 4,
                'B', "Y", 2022, 3, 5,
                'B', "Y", 2023, 4, 6) %>% 
 mutate(trial = factor(trial, levels = c("B", "X", "Y"))) %>% 
  arrange(grp, trial, yr)
```

Now, I need to use `group_by()`, but I can't group on `trial` as I need to use the baseline, `B` in calculations for both "X" and "Y".

```
undesired_outcome_tidier_code <- tabl %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% # this do not work!
  mutate(Value1.1 = cumsum(value1),
         Value2.1 = lag(cumsum(value2), default = 0),
         Value3   = Value1.1 + Value2.1) %>% 
         select(-Value1.1, -Value2.1)
```

In `undesired_outcome_tidier_code` row 4-5 and 9-10 is, for obvious reasons, not using line 1 and 6, respectively, as base line. As shown here,

```
undesired_outcome_tidier_code
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   grp [2]
   grp   trial    yr value1 value2 Value3
   <chr> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     B      2021      2      0      2
 2 A     X      2022      3      1      5
 3 A     X      2023      4      2     10
 4 A     Y      2022      5      3     17
 5 A     Y      2023      6      4     26
 6 B     B      2021      0      2      0
 7 B     X      2022      1      3      3
 8 B     X      2023      2      4      8
 9 B     Y      2022      3      5     15
10 B     Y      2023      4      6     24
```

I am looking for a solution that gets me `desired_outcome` (see below) in a tidy way.

I can, in this smaller example, work my way around it, to get to my `desired_outcome`, but it's a *cumbersome* two step solution. There must be a better/tidier way.

```
step1 <- tabl  %>% arrange(grp, trial, yr)  %>% filter(trial  != 'Y') %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(Value1.1 = cumsum(value1),
         Value2.1 = lag(cumsum(value2), default = 0),
         Value3   = Value1.1 + Value2.1)

step2 <- tabl  %>% arrange(grp, trial, yr)  %>% filter(trial  != 'X') %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(Value1.1 = cumsum(value1),
         Value2.1 = lag(cumsum(value2), default = 0),
         Value3   = Value1.1 + Value2.1)
    
desired_outcome <- rbind(step1, 
      step2 %>% filter(trial  != 'B') 
                         ) %>% select(-Value1.1, -Value2.1) %>% arrange(grp, trial, yr)
```

Comment: I tried a slightly more explicit title and expanded the explanation. I hope you don't mind :) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

With the addition of `purrr`, you could do:

```
map(.x = c("X", "Y"),
    ~ tabl %>%
     arrange(grp, trial, yr) %>%
     filter(trial != .x) %>%
     group_by(grp) %>% 
     mutate(value3 = cumsum(value1) + lag(cumsum(value2), default = 0))) %>% 
 reduce(full_join) %>%
 arrange(grp, trial, yr) 

  grp   trial    yr value1 value2 value3
   <chr> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     B      2021      2      0      2
 2 A     X      2022      3      1      5
 3 A     X      2023      4      2     10
 4 A     Y      2022      5      3      7
 5 A     Y      2023      6      4     16
 6 B     B      2021      0      2      0
 7 B     X      2022      1      3      3
 8 B     X      2023      2      4      8
 9 B     Y      2022      3      5      5
10 B     Y      2023      4      6     14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this.

- `calculate_value3` is a function that calculates `value3` as you described. It does it for every letter of `trial`. It always includes the observation of the baseline. It doesn't matter if the letters will be different than X and Y. Note that `baseline` can be any letter you want, I set it up as "B" for now.
- Inside the pipes, you go for a `map-reduce` solution. `map` will run the function `calculate_value3` for each unique `trial` and `reduce` will set them all together with `coalesce` (which will replace all `NA`s --> this is why I initialize `v3` as a vector of all `NA`s in `calculate_value3`)

```r
calculate_value3 <- function(ut, # trial under examination
                             tr, # trial vector
                             v1, # value1 vector
                             v2, # value2 vector
                             baseline = "B"){ # baseline id
  
  v3      <- rep_len(NA, length(tr))
  ind     <- ut == tr | baseline == tr
  cumv1   <- cumsum(v1[ind]) 
  cumlv2  <- cumsum(lag(v2[ind], default = 0)) 
  v3[ind] <- cumv1 + cumlv2
  v3
  
}

library(purrr)
tabl %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(value3 = reduce(
    
    map(unique(trial), calculate_value3,
        tr = trial, v1 = value1, v2 = value2), 
    
    coalesce)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    grp   trial    yr value1 value2 value3
#>    <chr> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A     B      2021      2      0      2
#>  2 A     X      2022      3      1      5
#>  3 A     X      2023      4      2     10
#>  4 A     Y      2022      5      3      7
#>  5 A     Y      2023      6      4     16
#>  6 B     B      2021      0      2      0
#>  7 B     X      2022      1      3      3
#>  8 B     X      2023      2      4      8
#>  9 B     Y      2022      3      5      5
#> 10 B     Y      2023      4      6     14
```

The solution is flexible to the identifiers of the trials and seems reasonably easy to debug and to edit if need be [at least to me].

Answer (score 1):

Because `tidyverse` didn't seem like a strict requirement, I take the opportunity to suggest a `data.table` alternative:

Starting with the 'desired_outcome' data, just to make it easier to compare results:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(desired_outcome)

desired_outcome[ , v3 := {
  c(value1[1], sapply(c("X", "Y"), function(g){
    .SD[trial %in% c("B", g), (cumsum(value1) + cumsum(shift(value2, fill = 0)))[-1]]
  }))}, by = grp]

#     grp trial   yr value1 value2 Value3 v3
#  1:   A     B 2021      2      0      2  2
#  2:   A     X 2022      3      1      5  5
#  3:   A     X 2023      4      2     10 10
#  4:   A     Y 2022      5      3      7  7
#  5:   A     Y 2023      6      4     16 16
#  6:   B     B 2021      0      2      0  0
#  7:   B     X 2022      1      3      3  3
#  8:   B     X 2023      2      4      8  8
#  9:   B     Y 2022      3      5      5  5
# 10:   B     Y 2023      4      6     14 14
```

For each 'grp' (`by = grp`), loop over 'trial' "X" and "Y" (`sapply(c("X", "Y")`). Within each sub-dataset defined by `by` (`.SD`), select rows where 'trial' is equal to "B" or the current value of the loop (`trial %in% c("B", g)`).

Do the calculation (`cumsum(value1) + cumsum(shift(value2, fill = 0))` and remove the first value (`[-1]`). Append the first row within each 'grp', i.e. the row that corresponds to trial "B" (`c(value1[1], ...`). Assign the result to a new variable by reference (`v3 :=` )